# Quais os principais cuidados que devo ter em mente para minha aplicação funcionar corretamente em navegadores diferentes?

Tags: php, ajax, xhtml

Programo pequenos sistemas utilizando xhtml, ajax e php. Quando monto o código vou testando as partes no **Chrome** ferramenta de desenvolvedor (Ctr+I) e no phptester.net. Quando termino minha aplicação tenho que debugar tudo de novo para que rode corretamente no **Firefox** e no **Internet Explorer**. Quais principais cuidados devo ter para minimizar essa debugação final?

Comment: Nao levar em conta o IE6.

Comment: Não faço debug segmentado no IE. Simplesmente rodo todas as funções da aplicação como se fosse o usuário e tento achar coisas estranhas, o que acho vou resolvendo...

Comment: Com o devido +1 na resposta do Caffé, este é o tipo de pergunta que rola de deixar sem aceite por mais tempo pois atrai mais "competidores" por uma boa resposta.

Comment: Eu faço o caminho inverso, produzo e testo no IE, ficando bom nele é quase certo que vai ficar bom nos outros... Mas o elemento que sempre da diferença é o maldito select, este fica diferente em cada navegador, eles não conseguem fazer num padrão!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Os recursos que não estejam na definição padrão do [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/web/web_standards.asp), [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html) e [JavaScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) são resolvidos de maneira diferente por cada navegador; e mesmo os recursos padronizados algumas vezes também são resolvidos de maneira diferente, por bug ou por decisão do fornecedor.

Nós desenvolvedores temos utilizado por exemplo muito HTML5, mas esta versão do HTML ainda não está liberada então é com recursos específicos desta versão que temos mais diferença de comportamento entre os navegadores (o que não está fechado é suportado de maneira distinta por cada navegador, ou sequer é suportado).

Então infelizmente não tem mágica: você terá que continuar testando e adaptando seu código para que rode bem em todos os navegadores, e quanto mais rica você quiser tua interface com o usuário, mais incompatibilidades você encontrará (pois os recursos mais básicos já estão maduros e padronizados entre os navegadores).

Algumas práticas para minimizar seu retrabalho:

- Desenhe sua página de modo a ficar bem apresentável mesmo com diferenças de layout entre os navegadores (utilizando layout fluído em vez de posições e tamanhos fixos, por exemplo).
- Escolha um navegador como sendo o seu "recomendado". Utilize recursos específicos para melhorar a experiência do usuário neste navegador, mas não deixe seu aplicativo depender deste recurso para funcionar (o aplicativo funcionará de maneira alternativa ainda que menos bacana quando não estiver rodando no navegador "recomendado").
- Utilize frameworks que abstraem as diferenças de comportamento entre os navegadores (por exemplo JQuery).
- Ao utilizar um recurso ou biblioteca ou framework verifique quais navegadores e respectivas versões ele suporta.

Comment: Infelizmente o 1º é a mais triste verdade...

Answer (score 5):

Complementando a resposta do @Caffé:

No caso específico do Javascript, você pode usar um *framework* de testes, como o [qUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) (da mesma equipe do jQuery).

Com ele, você pode escrever testes que garantem que o seu código funciona corretamente. E como ele roda direto no navegador, você pode rodá-lo em cada um dos navegadores para verificar se está tudo OK. Mas lembre-se que, dependendo de como sua aplicação está estruturada, pode ser difícil testá-la. Quanto mais modular, melhor.

Talvez você se interesse em ler mais sobre [Test Driven Development](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Driven_Development).

---

E como o @Caffé já disse, normalmente os desenvolvedores de *frameworks* e bibliotecas como o [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), etc. **já testaram** seus códigos em navegadores diferentes. Assim, trabalhar em cima deles costuma diminuir a margem para problemas.

Eu particularmente também recomendo evitar o uso excessivo de Javascript. Gerar o HTML no servidor é mais fácil, inclusive a manutenção. Use Javascript para o que é realmente necessário.